# Combine Two File Deletion Functions Into One With A Wildcard - PHP

Tags: php, loops, file, wildcard

I have a folder that contains two sizes of avatar image (50x wide and 250px wide). I'm currently deleting them with two foreach functions when a new profile avatar is uploaded.

In the code below the `$destinationFolder` is the directory the files are in, the `'250-'` is a string prefix for the filename based on image size and `$db_profileImage` is the filename that is assigned when the image is originally uploaded (this includes the file ext e.g. jpg/png). The image is also deleted from a MySQL database via a PDO Prepared Statement.

```
// DELETE PREVIOUS PROFILE IMAGES FROM FOLDER WHEN NEW IMAGE IS UPLOADED
foreach(glob($destinationFolder . '250-' . $db_profileImage) as $i){
    unlink($i);
}
foreach(glob($destinationFolder . '50-' . $db_profileImage) as $i){
    unlink($i);
}

// an example filename would be:
'50-613a9f679a072.png'
```

I also need to create this functionality on my main images folder which has 5 different sizes of image that are produced when an image is uploaded (and thus will need to be removed when deleted), and I would like to replace the size prefix with a wild card (which I think is the best way to approach this?). In other words replace the `'250-'` and `'50'` with a wildcard character and have one foreach function.

Any help/advice much appreciated on a) if I'm approaching this correctly, and if so the best way to incorporate the 'wildcard' character.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use braces to satisfy both conditions:

```
foreach(glob($destinationFolder . '{250,50}-' . $db_profileImage, GLOB_BRACE) as $i) {
    // rest of code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that works on my local MAMP - the only thing that mildly worries me is in the PHP docs it say `The GLOB_BRACE flag is not available on some non GNU systems`. Does that mean it will work on all Linux OS systems? I'm not up on that side of things

Comment: @paulo_cam a valid concern, yes it should work, what is the os of your production server by the way?

Comment: It is going to be on SiteGround which by the look of it use Fedora